# can we have any jmeter control over the threads?

Tags: jmeter

can we have any control over the threads?

Consider i have 10 threads and i have provided my test data in .csv file. so can  I control on threads like which thread should pick which data and may be some delay for few of the threads?

Also, can someone suggest me some book or online content wherein i can have information on internals of JMeter. Like when we run test plan, what all things are happening on memory side, reading of different properties files, receiving response, how threads internally works, etc.

Thanks, 
Abhishek

Answer (score 0):

JMeter is a very flexible and powerful tool.  In theory, anything is possible it all depends on what your testing goals are.  Even things not supported by JMeter can be coded in Java and easily integrated with a [Java Sampler](https://newspaint.wordpress.com/2012/11/28/creating-a-java-sampler-for-jmeter/).  Your question indicates you have not spent a lot of time experimenting with the tool, but hopefully my answer jump-starts that process for you.

JMeter has a lot of control features that can be used in conjunction with CSV data to control the flow of a thread.  For example, use the CSV data to correctly enter the right block of a Switch Controller, validate an If Controller, or control the number of loops in a Loop Controller.  Be sure you read the entire [Getting Started Guide](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html) and familiarize yourself with the [Component Reference Guide](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html)

In terms of how things work internally, your best bet is to build the JMeter project from source in an IDE like Eclipse.  You can then step through the entire program in as much detail as you want.
Tutorial: [Build JMeter from Source](http://artur.ejsmont.org/blog/content/how-to-build-jmeter-from-sources-in-eclipse)

Also, the /bin/jmeter file has a decent number of comments about how to properly configure JVM memory for a JMeter process.

You probably want to install at least the most basic [JMeter Plugin Package](http://jmeter-plugins.org/).

Lastly, if you need one thread to control the behavior of another thread you can use [FIFO Queues](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/InterThreadCommunication/) or set JVM properties via Beanshell which are global and not unique to a thread like runtime variables.

```
props.put("key","value");
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. For getting internals of JMeter you suggested to go through the code, but as i am not developer it will be very hard to understand it. That's why i was looking for some content.